# Property "Listener" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, properties, listener

I create a Viewscreen in my main activity that extends ScreenView. There are two public booleans I want to create listeners for in my Viewscreen.

```
public class Mainactivity extends Activity {
    private ViewScreen view;
    private PropertyChangeEvent event1;
    private PropertyChangeEvent event2;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        view= new ViewScreen(this);
        setContentView(view);
        event1= new PropertyChangeEvent(view, "boolean1",false,true);
        event2= new PropertyChangeEvent(view, "boolean2",false,true);
new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            if (view.boolean1) {dothing1();}
            }
    };
}
```

I want these listeners to detect multiple changes. For example (b1 is boolean1):

b1=false-->b1=true, then we do thing1.

Then b1=true-->b1=false, we do nothing.

Then b1=false-->b1=true, we do thing1 again.

Why isn't it working?

Comment: what's a screenview?

Comment: ScreenView basically holds your canvas and manages the draw method. It can also react to onTouch events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for everyone out there having trouble. To use PropertyChangeEvent it's SUPER simple.

So on a higher level look you've got:

1. Your "Activity" which holds [2]
2. Your "object"

for both you'll want to
`import java.beans.*;`

In your object you've got the property you want to track (maybe a button click or if you're making a game, whether or not they are dead/alive). We'll call it boolean1

So to track boolean1 you must make a PropertyChangeSupport.

```
public class Object extends[whatever you like] implements [whatever you want]{

public boolean1=false;
public PropertyChangeSupport changes = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

public void yourapplication(){
//you're doing whatever you're application does here
...
boolean1=true; //something happened (maybe the player lost)
this.changes.firePropertyChange("boolean1",false,true); // So we tell our listener
... 
// the rest of your application happens 
         } 
}
```

Alright we've defined our object with the minimal amount of info to tell our listener "something happened"

```
public class Main extends Activity{
private Object obj;
public PropertyChangeListener listener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    obj= new Object(this);
    listener= new PropertyChangeListener() { //This is how we define the listener and tell it what to do when it hears something change
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            if (obj.boolean1) {
                dothing1();
                obj.boolean1=false;
            }
        }
    };
    obj.changes.addPropertyChangeListener(listener); //The Support class binds the property change listener to our Object
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to read about **Observer Design Pattern**

Comment: I've taken a swing at it after this post. This doesn't tell me why what I'm doing isn't working.

Comment: What view have you bound the PrioertyChangeListener to?

Comment: PropertyChangeEvent is a constructor creating the event flags. Then I try using this to listen for event flags: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html

Comment: I am trying to bind my two event flags to my global variable "view" which is essentially a java object with properties.

Comment: But when you're creating that new PropertyChangeListener block,  you aren't saving the reference anywhere and hence that block doesn't seem to be bound with any view.  It looks like just a vague definition of a call-back without anything using it

Comment: How could I do it differently? I think you're right that the problem is the listener isn't "hearing" either event1 or event2. I looked at tutorials using PropertyChangeEvent and I can't figure out how I am using it incorrectly

Comment: Yes,  a Listener needs to be bound to a view so that it can listen to the events happening on that view.  Example : if you want to listen to the click event of a button in Android you'd do something like this : button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v) {}) ;